# How can I make a Python object always return true for an equality test?

Tags: python, object, equality

**EDIT: The following code had a simple mistake which didn't actually illustrate the problem.  I've left it here(uncorrected), but I'm still curious about answers to the questions at the bottom.**

I have the following object in Python, that is supposed to always return true for an equality test:

```
class Wildcard(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

It works in some cases, but not all:

```
>>> w = Wildcard()
>>> w == 'g'
True
>>> 'g' == w
True
>>> w == 10
True
>>> 10 == 'w'
False
```

From my understand, the == operator passes the second operand into the __ eq__ method of the first, which explains why w == 10 works but 10 == w does not.  This raises two questions.  First, is it possible to construct that object that has this property regardless of which operand it is?  Second, why does this work on a string, but not an int?  What about String's __ eq__ method makes it evaluate 'g' == w to True?

Comment: The last line is not comparing `w` and `10`, but `'w'` and `10`

Comment: @thefourtheye -- It's a reasonable observation (obviously an oversight on the part of OP), but it doesn't _really_ address the question -- _Can I make an object which equals everything regardless of whether it is the first or second argument?_  And the corollary, _Why do some objects seem to delegate equality to the second argument and not others?_  I wish OP would clean up the question a bit and remove the errors, but I think it's a valid question at it's core.

Comment: Why not just use True instead of comparing... I know this doesnt help but what's the point in returning True

Comment: @user3570335 -- presumably because OP doesn't know what object (or type) is actually going to be used in the comparison -- This allows him/her to create an object which could take different code paths than normal (e.g. when mocking)

Comment: @thefourtheye Wow, simple mistake on my part, thanks.  I am still curious about answers to the questions.  I updated the question to reflect the mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to construct such an object.  Consider:

```
>>> class Wildcard(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
... 
>>> w = Wildcard()
>>> w == 10
True
>>> 10 == w
True
>>> class Joker(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
... 
>>> j = Joker()
>>> w == j
True
>>> j == w
False
```

There is no reason for `w` (a `Wildcard`) to take precedence over `j` (a `Joker`) in this scenario.

---

Now, you might be wondering why this works for strings and ints -- It's because if the class's test returns the singleton `NotImplemented`, then the test is delegated from the first argument to the second:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, Wildcard):
...             return NotImplemented
...         else:
...             return False
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> 
>>> f == 1
False
>>> f == Foo()
False
>>> f == w
True
```

Answer (score 8):

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY

assert ANY == 2
assert 2 == ANY
assert (4, 2) == (ANY, 2)
assert "abc" == ANY
assert ANY == "abc"
assert ANY == False
assert ANY == True
assert ANY == None
assert ANY
```

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the question, but it's useful to know that an object like OP's Wildcard already exists in the standard library.

Comment: Also: https://github.com/hypothesis/h-matchers